# More publications on Miska the Wolf-Spider?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, planes

I'm curious about Miska the Wolf-Spider, 2nd (Known) Prince of Demons, in *Dungeons & Dragons* Great Wheel Cosmology.

Miska was raised to power by the "Queen of Chaos" after stripping the title away from Obox-ob. Defeated by the wind dukes and imprisoned in his castle out-of-time in pandemonium. A short little stint at trying to obtain freedom in the Rod of Seven parts adventure but failed, and that's it. The Queen of Chaos is apparently continually searching for ways to free him (*FC:I*), and not doing much else.

Do we have any other publications that go into more detail on this figure outside of the [*The Rod of Seven Parts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rod_of_Seven_Parts) adventure, and the brief blurb in [*Fiendish Codex I*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiendish_Codex_I:_Hordes_of_the_Abyss)?

I am interesting in using this character for my own campaign but would like to scrape as much 'official' information that I can find. Any and all information across editions would be useful, even if they are contradicting. (Please include sources!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The Rod of Seven Parts* and *Fiendish Codex I* are the primary sources for information on Miska the Wolf-Spider, but some other sources mention some details:

#### Magazines

The [Planescape Index](https://www.rilmani.org/psIndex.txt) lists the following magazine pages as referencing Miska or Mishka the Wolf Spider (spelling varies between publication):

- Dragon #343, page 67: An ancient druidic cult who created the ettercap race is speculated to have worshipped a spider fiend servant of Mishka the Wolf Spider.
- Dragon #347, page 36: Mentions Miska's alliance with Ogrémoch, the evil earth archomental, during the Battle of Pesh.
- Dragon #349, page 31: In *The Demonomicon of Iggwilv: Dagon, Prince of Darkened Depths*, Miska is mentioned among some abyssal history.
- Dragon #353, page 48: The good earth archomental Sunnis is mentioned for her role in fighting Ogrémoch at the battle of Pesh, allowing the Wind Dukes to defeat Miska.
- Dragon #357, page 21: In *The Demonomicon of Iggwilv: Demogorgon, Prince of Demons*, Miska's rise to power and subsequent fall are detailed.
- Dungeon #147, page 81: In the Savage Tide adventure module *Into the Maw*, an iron statue depicts Miska kneeling before Demogorgon.

The index omits a few minor references:

- Dragon #224: *A History of the Rod of Seven Parts* naturally mentions Miska
- Dragon #233, *The Rod of Seven Parts world by world*, briefly mentions a hypothetical plot by the baatezu to recover the Rod to defeat Miska

#### AD&D 2e

- AD&D 2e's Dungeon Master's Guide
- Book of Artifacts, in reference to the Rod of Seven Parts
- Encyclopedia Magica Vol 3, in reference to the Rod of Seven parts (originally from the Book of Artifacts)

#### D&D 3e

- Fiendish Codex I: pages 73, 106, 139, and 148, according to the Planescape Index
- Elder Evils, p.112: A brief mention of Miska's defeat at the Battle of Pesh.
- The Age of Worms adventure path, Dungeon issues #124-135
- The Age of Worms Overload, a web enhancement released by Paizo for that adventure path
- The Dungeon magazine web enhancements for issues 124 and 129

#### D&D 4e

- The Demonomicon. In 4e continuity, Miska is a primordial in the service of Tharizdun.
- Against the Cult of Chaos, an adventure module featuring Miska. A cult worships Miska, who is trapped on another plane, but his power leaks into the material world and several artifacts have been forged from Miska's power. (If this were D&D 5e, Miska would make an excellent warlock patron.)
- Heroes of the Elemental Chaos, which names Miska as a demonic primordial. A *blade of chaos* is made from a fragment of metal worn by Miska.

#### D&D 5e

- Monster Manual, under the aarakocra monster entry, mentions their battle with Mishka.
- Elemental Evil Player's Companion, which mentions that it was the chaos in Mishka's blood which shattered the Rod of Law.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't much outside of the Rod of Seven Parts adventure. Miska is mentioned or detailed in only a few places

- 2nd Edition DMG - Mentioned briefly, under the listing for the Rod of Seven Parts sample artifacts
- 2nd Edition Book of Artifacts - Brief mention/description, as related to the Rod and its destruction
- Dragon Magazine #224 - Article on the history of the Rod, minor mention/description
- Rod of Seven Parts sourcebook/adventure - Multiple mentions, including description and stats, etc
- Dungeon Magazine complete Adventure Path Age of Worms - a couple of brief mentions.

The last one (Dungeon magazine) however, makes mention of Miska actually being another name for the efreeti Memnon.

> [...] Their ancient foes were the armies of Memnonnar (Chaos army) led by the great efreet general Memnon (Miska the Wolf-Spider) in service to Kossuth (Queen of Chaos) the elemental Lord of Fire.

I cannot find another corroboration of the last supposition, and these are the only mentions of Miska that I have found. There does exist the chance that Miska was detailed in a fiction novel, however.

As noted by @quadratic wizard in the comments, the above references were substitution suggestions:

> The Age of Worms Overload document in which that quote appears notes that parentheses refer to suggested adaptations for placing the adventure in the Forgotten Realms. For example, Diamond Lake is replaced with Daggerford, and the Rod of Seven Parts replaced with the Shattered Scepter of Calim.

Comment: Memnon as Miska that is almost contradicting indeed. Which Dragon magazine can we find that in?

Comment: @L.P. As stated in the answer, dungeon magazine adventure path age of worms. As noted by another commenter that was solely a substitution/flavor option, not an actual depiction.